# Is it possible to use RedirectToAction() inside a custom AuthorizeAttribute class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Using ASP.Net MVC 2, is there any way to use the [RedirectToAction()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction.aspx) method of the [Controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505093%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) class inside a class that is based on the `AuthorizeAttribute` class?

```
public class CustomAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase context) {
        // Custom authentication goes here
        return false;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext context) {
        base.OnAuthorization(context);

        // This would be my ideal result
        context.Result = RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller");
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to re-direct the user to a specific controller / action when they fail the authentication instead of returning them to the login page. Is it possible to have the re-direct URL generated for that controller / action and then use [RedirectResult()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.redirectresult.aspx)? I'm trying to avoid the temptation to just hard-code the URL.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can/should override `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` instead of `OnAuthorization`. Here's the default implementation:

```
    protected virtual void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
        // Returns HTTP 401 - see comment in HttpUnauthorizedResult.cs.
        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
```

You can't use `Controller.RedirectToAction`, but you *can* return a new `RedirectToRouteResult`.

So you can do:

```
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
        // Returns HTTP 401 - see comment in HttpUnauthorizedResult.cs.
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                                   new RouteValueDictionary 
                                   {
                                       { "action", "ActionName" },
                                       { "controller", "ControllerName" }
                                   });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Good catch on using HandleUnauthorizedRequest - I was using OnAuthorization because I saw it in another tutorial/discussion (they had a custom property that was set when authentication failed that would trigger the re-direct).

Comment: @LanceMcNearney What would i pass in the parameter filterContext?

Comment: @Craig Stuntz What would i pass in as filterContext?

Comment: @Pomster: You don't pass anything. MVC passes that in for you. Generally, don't call it directly.

Comment: You've made my day by the grace of Almighty Allah.

Comment: When I use this one, i am getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. Can any one help me out? Some how authorize is getting called too many times and resulting in the above error.

Answer (score 13):

You can do something like this:

```
var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
routeValues["controller"] = "ControllerName";
routeValues["action"] = "ActionName";
//Other route values if needed.
context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeValues);
```

This is the way the framework does it when you call "RedirectToAction()" in your controller.

Comment: What is context? i have it underlined in red?

Comment: @Pomster Check out the question, "context" is a parameter to the method the question is about.

Comment: Thanks, What would be passed in to make this work? Iv been struggling to get this working

Comment: This is a action filter attribute that needs to be added to the controller, to the action or registered as a global filter.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else is interested in this question.
This can be solved in a simpler way (at least using MVC 3, don't know about MVC 2):

Just create a small private controller in your custom AuthorizeAttribute:

```
    private class RedirectController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult RedirectWhereever()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller");
        }

    }
```

This can easily be used in your HandleUnauthorizedRequest method (see Craigs answer):

```
filterContext.Result = (new RedirectController()).RedirectWhereever();
```

Comment: `RedirectToAction` returns an `RedirectToRouteResult`, there is no need to create a controller just to return one, as @Craig Stuntz's answered