# MVC 3 AuthorizeAttribute Redirect with Custom Message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

How can I create a custom AuthorizeAttribute that specifies a message in the form of a string parameter and then passes that along to the login page?

For example, ideally it would be cool to do this:

```
[Authorize(Message = "Access to the blah blah function requires login. Please login or create an account")]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    return View();
}
```

Then, in the Login action, I could do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Login(string message = "")
{
    ViewData.Message = message;

    return View();
}
```

And finally in the view I can do this:

```
@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewData.Message))
{
    <div class="message">@ViewData.Message</div>
}

<form> blah blah </form>
```

Basically I want to pass a custom message to the login page so I can display a message specific to what the user is trying to access at that particular time.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var result = new ViewResult();
        result.ViewName = "Login.cshtml";        //this can be a property you don't have to hard code it
        result.MasterName = "_Layout.cshtml";    //this can also be a property
        result.ViewBag.Message = this.Message;
        filterContext.Result = result;
    }
```

Usage:

```
    [CustomAuthorize(Message = "You are not authorized.")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: What if I wanted to redirect to an specific View/Controller/ Routing parameters , how would it be?

Comment: @ClayKaboom See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472578/is-it-possible-to-use-redirecttoaction-inside-a-custom-authorizeattribute-clas

Comment: Note that you probably don't want to include the ".cshtml" in the ViewName property. When I did, it looked for Login.cshtml.cshtml .

Answer (score 3):

web.config

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms name="SqlAuthCookie"
           loginUrl="~/Account/LogOnYouHavenotRight" 
           timeout="2880"     />
 </authentication>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult LogOnYouHavenotRight()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
    }
```

In **both** Views:

```
Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account" )
```

Comment: only part of the whole answer but if you read the others you might be clever enough to sum them so +1 anyway....