# MVC OnAuthorization redirect to controller/action with model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**UPDATE**
Not a duplicate as per above as that question routes to an explicit view, not a controller/action

I am using a custom authorisation (at controller level) to ensure that a user can only access specific functions of an application (held in an external access control system).

Below is the `AuthorizeAttribute` class

```
public class MyCustomAuth : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        string ctrl = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];

        bool isAuth = GetAuthorizedFunctions(HttpContext.Current.User).Any(f => f.Controller.Equals(ctrl, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        if (!isAuth)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Contact", action = "Index", AuthMsg = "Sorry, unauthorized" }));
        }
    }
}
```

Bascially, if the user requests a function that they are not authorised to access, then I redirect then to the "Contact" page to show a suitable message.

However, in the above, the AuthMessage is encoded into the URL string..

`http://localhost/HotelRequests/Contact?AuthMsg=Sorry%2C%20unauthorized`

How can I pass this message without it being shown in the URL, preferable as a ViewModel required for the Contact page.

Comment: Either you can send a code in query string and in controller's action you can show a message based on code or encrypt the message in query string so that it is visible but not readable and in action decrypt to show message in view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC 3 AuthorizeAttribute Redirect with Custom Message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922838/mvc-3-authorizeattribute-redirect-with-custom-message)

Comment: Not really a "duplicate" because it requires redirect to an explicit view, rather than a Controller/Action but its another approach I guess.

Comment: i guess TempData is available on redirection

Comment: TempData does not appear to be (or I can't find it) ... But Session is (via `filterContext.HttpContext.Session` ... Another option...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TempData has more life than ViewBag or ViewData

```
  filterContext.Controller.TempData["AuthMsg "] = "Sorry, unauthorized";
  filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Contact", action = "Index" }));
```

Read it in Contact's Index method as..

```
ViewBag.Message = TempData["AuthMsg "].ToString();
```

Comment: TempData not surfaced in OnAuthorization() method

Comment: Updated to `filterContext.Controller.TempData[]`

Comment: i don't have my machine right now will test it later, thanks. i guess this should work now