# Proper way to redirect to an action from within a class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

### Background

I have a project split between Web Forms & MVC (moving towards MVC, thankfully).

I have a `LoginManager` class that takes in an `IRedirectionManager` class, and based on user properties (is authenticated, password expired, hasn't accepted terms) calls different methods on the Redirection manager (RedirectToLogin, RedirectToAcceptTerms, etc.)

I'm working to build and implement the "Redirect Manager" for our MVC controllers.

### Questions

- Should this be an ActionFilter or a Base Class? It appears that I could use either, but am not sure if that's actually the case.
- What is the appropriate way to redirect to an action or route in MVC? For the web forms RedirectManager, I was passing in the response object and using `Response.Redirect` to get to the page. I'd love to be able to use something like `RedirectToAction`, etc. to make this work.

### Code

In case it helps to clarify. The `LoginManager`:

```
public class LoginManager
{
    private IRedirectManager _redirectManager;
    private string _returnUrl;
    private ClaimsIdentity _currentUser;

    public LoginManager(string attemptingToAccessUrl, ClaimsIdentity identity, IRedirectManager redirectManager)
    {
        if (redirectManager == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("redirectManager"); }
        if (identity == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("identity"); }

        _redirectManager = redirectManager;
        _currentUser = identity;
        _returnUrl = attemptingToAccessUrl;
    }

    public void CheckLoginAndRedirect()
    {
        if (!_currentUser.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_returnUrl)) { _redirectManager.RedirectToLogin(); }
            else { _redirectManager.RedirectToLogin(_returnUrl); }
        }

        if (_currentUser.IsDisabled()) { _redirectManager.RedirectToDisabled(); }

        if (UserRequiresPasswordReset()) { _redirectManager.RedirectToResetPassword(_returnUrl); }

        if (!_currentUser.HasAcceptedTerms()) {
            if (_currentUser.IsExternalUser()){ _redirectManager.RedirectToTermsAcceptance(_returnUrl); }
        }

        if (PasswordIsAboutToExpire())
        {
            if (!_currentUser.HasDeclinedToChangePassword()) { _redirectManager.RedirectToPasswordExpiringSoon(_returnUrl); }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of the `WebFormsRedirectManager`:

```
public class WebFormsRedirectManager : IRedirectManager
{
    private HttpContext _httpContext;

    public WebFormsRedirectManager(HttpContext currentHttpContext)
    {
        if (currentHttpContext == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("currentHttpContext");}

        _httpContext = currentHttpContext;
    }

    public void RedirectToLogin()
    {
        _httpContext.Response.Redirect("~/AccountManagement/Login");

    }
}
```

And an example of how I use it in my `ProtectedPage` class, which other web forms pages inherit from:

```
public class ProtectedPage : BasePage
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        var redirector = new WebFormsRedirectManager(Context);
        new LoginManager(null, ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity as ClaimsIdentity, redirector).CheckLoginAndRedirect();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a filter action and then redirect from it like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453338/redirect-from-action-filter-attribute

Comment: More information that might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472578/is-it-possible-to-use-redirecttoaction-inside-a-custom-authorizeattribute-clas

Comment: @abatishchev, FYI, I reverted your edits of the heading formats (personal / visual preference).

Comment: I can't insist, this is your question, anyway. My point is just to decrease font size the paragraphs not to yell so much.

Comment: @abatishchev I (very respectfully) disagree. Headings in this case are used to denote different sections of the question in case users want to skip background info, etc. Had I been using the headings for an entire sentence or to make a point, I would wholeheartedly agree with you. Thanks for outlining your reasoning!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the MVC source code `RedirectToAction()` returns a `RedirectoToRouteResult` object. This class is effectively doing what you are doing - calling `Response.Redirect()`.

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
    ...

    string destinationUrl = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(
        RouteName, null /* actionName */, null /* controllerName */, 
        RouteValues, Routes, context.RequestContext, 
        false /* includeImplicitMvcValues */);

    ...

    context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(destinationUrl, endResponse: false);
}
```