# Redirect within GlobalActionFilter is failing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I've created a GlobalActionFilter to redirect logged in users to designated pages on my site.  This is related to a previous question that I asked regarding global redirects ([Need recommendation for global, targeted redirects on ASP.NET MVC site for multiple differing conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020197/need-recommendation-for-global-targeted-redirects-on-asp-net-mvc-site-for-multi/))

Code in this GlobalActionFilter is being executed, but it's not redirecting the browser.  What am I missing?  Here is the code from the Global.asax.cs.  The ForceExternalUserCompletion() is my custom global action filter.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new Filters.ForceExternalUserCompletion());
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
}
```

Here is the code from my GlobalActionFilter.

```
/// <summary>
/// Direct a logged in ExternalUser to complete unfinished items.  Hierarchy is as follows:
/// 1. Security Questions
/// 2. Password Reset
/// </summary>
public class ForceExternalUserCompletion : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);

        HttpCookie externalUserCookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["ExternalUser"];
        if (externalUserCookie != null)
        {
            // 1. Security Questions
            if (externalUserCookie["ForceQA"] == "1")
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary 
                    { 
                        { "controller", "MyInfo" }, 
                        { "action", "ChangeSecurityQuestions" } 
                    });

                return;
            }

            // 2. Password Reset
            if (externalUserCookie["ForcePass"] == "1")
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary 
                    { 
                        { "controller", "MyInfo" }, 
                        { "action", "ChangePassword" } 
                    });

                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Via debugger I can see the code within this action filter is being executed. After the code block inside externalUserCookie["ForceQA"] == "1" runs, I expect to be redirected to the MyInfo/ChangeSecurityQuestions view, but that's not happening.  And no exception is being thrown.

Is using "filterContext.Result" the correct approach, and if so is there some additional line of code that I need to add so that this will successfully redirect the browser?

Thanks for your help.

=== Edit 3/13/2015 at 10:33 AM Central ===

Thanks everyone for your help and ideas. Right now I suspect something is wrong with my syntax for the RedirectToRouteResult.  If I replace that with this line of code, the browser redirects to Yahoo.

```
filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("http://www.yahoo.com");
```

=== Edit 3/13/2015 at 11:00 AM Central ===

Thanks Angelo and NightOwl.  Below is the fix that I ended up applying.

```
public class ForceExternalUserCompletion : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);

        HttpCookie externalUserCookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["ExternalUser"];
        if (externalUserCookie != null)
        {
            string controller = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
            string action = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

            // 1. Security Questions
            if (externalUserCookie["ForceQA"] == "1")
            {
                // Prevent a perpetual redirect.
                if (controller != "MyInfo" && action != "ChangeSecurityQuestions")
                {
                    filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.RedirectToRoute(
                        new RouteValueDictionary 
                    { 
                        { "controller", "MyInfo" }, 
                        { "action", "ChangeSecurityQuestions" } 
                    }
                    );
                }

                return;
            }

            // 2. Password Reset
            if (externalUserCookie["ForcePass"] == "1")
            {
                // Prevent a perpetual redirect.
                if (controller != "MyInfo" && action != "ChangePassword")
                {
                    filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.RedirectToRoute(
                        new RouteValueDictionary 
                    { 
                        { "controller", "MyInfo" }, 
                        { "action", "ChangePassword" } 
                    }
                    );
                }

                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The difference is that this fixed code uses RedirectToRoute instead of RedirectToRouteResult. And this also checks the current controller and action so that when the browser lands on one of the target pages, it doesn't cycle through a redirect loop. I'll clean this up a bit, but essentially this is fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: When you return a RedirectToRouteResult this sends a 302 (redirect) code to the browser and the browser will do a GET on the link provided calculated to that route. Is this not happening?

Comment: Thanks Angelo. That is correct. Per the Network tab in Firefox, no 302 is being sent to the browser. To rule out a browser-specific issue I've tried this with Chrome, IE, and Firefox.  But the result is the same. Also, I've added a couple of comments in each of these checks, to see if they get written to the browser, and they indeed are getting written.  Here is one of the comments that I inserted after the ForceQA cookie check: filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.Write("<!-- ForceQA -->");

Comment: Are there any MVC Areas in your code, the only thing I can think is that the controller information and action aren't mapping to a valid route, Do you have a MyInfoController with method ChangeSecurityQuestions that allow Gets?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. There is a MyInfoController with gets for ChangeSecurityQuestions and ChangePassword. I put breakpoints at each, and they never get called.

Comment: If you put the url /MyInfo/ChangeSecurityQuestions in the browser can you get to those breakpoints? This is just to validate if the route works properly.

Comment: Good idea. Yes, indeed it gets to those breakpoints when I navigate the browser to those routes directly.  I just put a Response.Redirect to Yahoo in my filter (see edit in my op) and that works. So it seems something is amiss with my RedirectToRouteResult.

Comment: Do you have any areas in your mvc project? If so you need to provide the area name to the route value dictionary also. What is the ful url you used to navigate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `RedirectToRouteResult` is suspicious because you are not calling the route out by name. I suspect that you are not getting a route match.

If you pass a parameter to the `name` parameter, you will be more likely to get a match.

```
public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    HttpCookie externalUserCookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["ExternalUser"];
    if (externalUserCookie != null)
    {
        // 1. Security Questions
        if (externalUserCookie["ForceQA"] == "1")
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                "Default",
                new RouteValueDictionary 
                { 
                    { "controller", "MyInfo" }, 
                    { "action", "ChangeSecurityQuestions" } 
                });

            return;
        }

        // 2. Password Reset
        if (externalUserCookie["ForcePass"] == "1")
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                "Default",
                new RouteValueDictionary 
                { 
                    { "controller", "MyInfo" }, 
                    { "action", "ChangePassword" } 
                });

            return;
        }
    }

    // If we made it here, pass the call on to the action method
    base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

It might be simpler if you just call `RedirectToAction`.

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToAction(action: "ChangePassword", controller: "MyInfo");
```

Comment: Thanks NightOwl888. I'll read that reference. I just tried removing base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext); altogether, and also moving it below the checks.  But neither change solved the redirect.

Comment: It was a shot in the dark, but didn't prove to be right. I have updated my answer because your redirect looks suspicious.

Comment: Ah, let me try that RedirectToAction. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right path. RedirectToAction wasn't resolving, so I replaced RedirectToRouteResult with RedirectToRoute.  I'll edit my OP to show the fix.