# ASP.NET MVC 5 OWIN Area Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin, area

I am building an `ASP.NET MVC 5` based web site that uses `OWIN` based authentication. I have created a new `Area` in the application for administrator panel. I would like to have a different login page than that of the normal user.

For instance, when i go to `http://site/admin/home/index` it should check for authorization and redirect to `http://site/admin/account/login` instead of going to site user login page.

I have already tried implementing a custom `Authorize` attribute. However, I somehow feel that it's not the right approach.

Could someone suggest a better or more right solution for this?

**Edit:** Custom attribute implementation

```
public class AuthorizeAreaAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(Url);
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
        }
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you think that it is not a good solution to go over a custom Authorize attribute?

Comment: @tire0011, I happened to see an internal exception being thrown `Headers were already sent!` when using custom attribute.

Comment: Can you post you code from the custom attribute?

Answer (score 2):

In `Configuration` method in `App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs` file you can change redirect behavoir.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
        // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, User>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)
        ),

        // Change redirect
        OnApplyRedirect = ApplyRedirect
    }
});

private static void ApplyRedirect(CookieApplyRedirectContext context) 
{
    Uri absoluteUri;
    PathString ContentVersioningUrlSegments = PathString.FromUriComponent("/admin/");

    if (Uri.TryCreate(context.RedirectUri, UriKind.Absolute, out absoluteUri)) 
    {
        PathString remainingPath;
        var path = PathString.FromUriComponent(absoluteUri);
        if (path.StartsWithSegments(ContentVersioningUrlSegments, out remainingPath) && remainingPath.HasValue && remainingPath.Value.Length > 1))
                context.RedirectUri = "url" +
                    new QueryString(
                        context.Options.ReturnUrlParameter,
                        context.Request.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
    }

    context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solved the problem using a method mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472578/is-it-possible-to-use-redirecttoaction-inside-a-custom-authorizeattribute-clas and it works well

Comment: Just want show the same solution without using custom attribute.